# Why notifications doesn't show as popup?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, popup

I implemented notifications in my app with Firebase. I can send notifications form Firebase to my phone but this notifications doesn't show as pop up, I can only see it if I scroll down from the top of my pohone to show notifications. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the notification chanels

```
// Default notifications channel
    String defaultChannelID = getString(R.string.notif_channel_default_ID);
    String defaultChannelName = getString(R.string.notif_channel_default_name);
    String defaultChannelDescription = getString(R.string.notif_channel_default_desctription);
    NotificationChannel defaultChannel = new NotificationChannel(defaultChannelID, defaultChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    defaultChannel.setDescription(defaultChannelDescription);

    // Alarms notifications channel
    String alarmChannelID = getString(R.string.notif_channel_alarms_ID);
    String alarmChannelName = getString(R.string.notif_channel_alarms_name);
    String alarmChannelDescription = getString(R.string.notif_channel_alarms_desctription);
    NotificationChannel alarmChannel = new NotificationChannel(alarmChannelID, alarmChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    alarmChannel.setDescription(alarmChannelDescription);

    // Create channels
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    List<NotificationChannel> notificationChannels = Arrays.asList(defaultChannel, alarmChannel);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannels(notificationChannels);
```

And here the FCM service

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        Log.e("Token", s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e("Notificacion recibida: ", remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            displayNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void displayNotification(String title, String body){
        String CHANNEL_ID = getString(R.string.notif_channel_alarms_ID);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

In other Stackoverflow posts they said that the problem is that I didn't put the notification inportance to HIGH, but, as you can see I writed that and the notifications isn't showing as pop up.

Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to implement is the so called "heads-up" notification. Unfortunately, even if you match the required criteria to have such a notification shown to the user, often the Android system by itself decides if it show's the "pop-up" from the top to the user or not.

One point where the heads-up notification probably won't be shown is when you have your respective application in foreground.

There is not much you can do, if you already match all the criteria that are mentioned in the following documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

**Note**: If you initially created your notification channel with a low priority and afterward updated it to a higher priority, it can help to reinstall your application.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answwr. I found in the settings of my app (I went here in my device: Setings->Applitacions-> <MyApp> -> Notifications) that the notification channel has the sound and the pop-up permission dissabled by default. When I turned it on, all the notifications make soung and are showing as pop-up. Is there any way to turn this setings on by default?? @J. Hegg